# Is there any way of speeding up my raycasting code?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have created a sphere in three.js which has around 140 circles on its surface.

[Have a look here if you like!](http://www.digitalfunfair.co.uk/three/jpots.html)

By clicking or touching a circle the user can change its colour.

Its a bit laggy on mobile devices though - is there any way of optimizing the following code?

```
function onMouseDown( e ) {


            mouseVector.x = 2 * (e.clientX / (window.innerWidth*0.8)) - 1;
            mouseVector.y = 1 - 2 * ( e.clientY / window.innerHeight );
            raycaster.setFromCamera( mouseVector, camera );

            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( circles );

            if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

                var intersect = intersects[ 0 ];
                pickedColor=parseInt(document.getElementById("color").value.replace('#', '0x'));

                intersect.object.material.color = new THREE.Color( pickedColor );
                render(); 


            }

        }
```

Comment: Before you do that, you are rendering too frequently. Remove `requestAnimationFrame()` and add this line after `controls` is created: `controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );` Secondly, create one `circleGeometry` and reuse it. See if that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It might have helped a bit but still noticeably laggy! Any other suggestions?

Comment: 1. `intersect.object.material.color.setHex( pickedColor );` 2. What line is slow? How do you know?

Comment: It was taking a long time to change colour once a circle was touched. I assumed it was the raycaster code but assumption is a dangerous thing. I swapped the mousedown code for on touchstart and the speed increased dramatically. I tried using the date & time to isolate the cause but couldn't get at the console messages on Android - think I need to root my phone. Anyway sorry for the wrong assessment of my problem but thank you very much for your optimisations - it did encourage me to look at things more logically!